# implementation of graphql-type-json

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Anyone with an idea on how I can implement graphql-type-json in my schema structure,I would like to get data in the form of key and value. I have tried reading through their docs but I cannot find a suitable way to implement in my code.

-graphql-type-json has been suggested a lot by people trying to assign json to graphql types.

```
"key":"customer_name",
"value":Emmanuel"
},
"key":"customer_id",
"value":"12"
},]
```

```js
const { authenticate, getCountryCode } = require('../utils');
import GraphQLJSON, { GraphQLJSONObject } from 'graphql-type-json';

const typeDef = `
  extend type Query {
    userData(countryCode:String!, idNumber:String, email:String, phoneNumber:String): Data
    userDatas(countryCode:String!): [Data!]!
}

type Data {
    customer_name:String
    customer_id_number:String
    dob:String
    phone_no:String
    email:String
    }
`;
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
      userData: authenticate(
      async (root, { countryCode, idNumber, email, phoneNumber }, { models }) => {

        // Get country specific data
        const country = getCountryCode(countryCode);
        // Get customer_id_number
        if (idNumber) {
          const idRecord = await models[`${country}_Data`].findOne({
            where: { customer_id_number: idNumber },
          });
          return idRecord

        } 
         else if(email){
          const emailRecord = await models[`${country}_Data`].findOne({
            where: { email: email },
          });
          return emailRecord

        }
         else if(phoneNumber){
          const phoneRecord = await models[`${country}_Data`].findOne({
            where: { phone_no: phoneNumber },
          });
          return phoneRecord

        }         

          else if (!idNumber || !email || !phoneNumber){
            throw new Error('Input the correct credentials');
          }  
          else{
             throw new Error('Input credentials');
          }    


      },
    ),

    // Get all burglaries
    userDatas: authenticate(async (root, { countryCode }, { models }) => {
      // Get country specific data
      const country = getCountryCode(countryCode);

      const transburglaries = await models[`${country}_Data`].findAll();

      transburglaries.forEach((data) => {
        data.countryCode = countryCode;
      });
      return transburglaries;
    }),
  },
};


module.exports = {
  typeDef,
  resolvers,
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: why *'I would like to get data in the form of key and value'* ? reason?

Comment: Just for learning purposes

Comment: define type as Seppe suggested (you don't need json types), learn to return data with matching shape, convert your DB/service/models records to that type shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey and welcome to Stack Overflow,

I'm not totally sure that I understand what you need but the way I interpret it you can try something like this:

```
Type KeyValuePair {
   key: String!
   value: String!
}
```

If my interpretation is wrong then please try to explain it again. Maybe with a concrete example of what you do need.

Greetjs

Comment: Thanks Seppe, that is the kind of format I am looking for, but I would like the key to reflect on to customer_name and value to the actual name of the customer.